# multiple string detections

Tags: regex, string, tidyverse

I need to detect a  patern in characters list with a negative lookbehind:

I have this type of data :

```
w \<- " HGQX0080 **HJFA0120** HGMA0030 ZCQH0010 **HGSA0010** ZZQX1880"

x \<- " HGQX0080 **HJFC0230** HGMA0030 ZZQX0270 ZZQX1880 ZCQH0010 **HGSA0010** ZZQX1880"

y \<- " HGQX0080 HGMA0030 ZZQX0270 ZZQX1880 ZCQH0010  ZZQX1880"

z \<- " HGMA0030 ZZQX0270 ZZQX1880 ZZQX0270 30098 ZZQX1880 **HGSA0010** ZCQH0010"

i mean : if there is no ("HJFC0230" **nor** "HJFA012") followed by the presence "HGSA0010"  == TRUE

w == F 

x == F

y == F

z == T

I try : str_detect(x, "(?\<!(HJFC023|HJFA012)).+(HGSA001)")
```

but not working the .+ makes the process fail.

Do you have any ideas?

thank for your help.

Comment: In most regex engines, lookbehinds needs to be of fixed width. So you can use positive lookahead and can use ! (not) in result.
Like in your case (?=(HJFC023|HJFA012)).*HGSA0010

Answer (score 0):

**To rephrase the problem**: *we need to match a string with a particular pattern if this string doesn't contain other patterns. If a string contains blacklisted words, we ignore/exclude this string.*

This is the version with a negative **look-ahead**: `^(?!.*(HJFA0120|HJFC0230)).*HGSA0010.*$`

In will match only the last string from the example: `z <- " HGMA0030 ZZQX0270 ZZQX1880 ZZQX0270 30098 ZZQX1880 HGSA0010 ZCQH0010"`.

Where:

- `(?!.*(HJFA0120|HJFC0230))` - a string doesn't contain **HJFA0120** or **HJFC0230** (negative look-ahead)
- `.*HGSA0010.*` - a string contains **HGSA0010**

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AEvjFU/1)